# Why does `==` behave differently inside `[ ... ]` in zsh and bash?

Tags: bash, zsh, test

I get what I expected when doing this in `bash`:

```
[ "a" == "a" ] && echo yes
```

It gave me `yes`.

But when I do this in `zsh`, I get the following:

```
zsh: = not found
```

Why does the same command (`/usr/bin/[`) behave differently in different shells?

Comment: it's not the same command - its a builtin found before `$PATH` is searched. and `==` isn't valid `test` syntax for the `/usr/bin/[` anway. Just `=` is fine.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's not `/usr/bin/[` in either of the shells. In Bash, you're using the [built-in `test`/`[` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-test), and [similarly in zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-test).

The difference is that [zsh also has an `=` expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#g_t_0060_003d_0027-expansion): `=foo` expands to the path to the `foo` executable. That means **`==` is treated as trying to find a command called `=` in your `PATH`**. Since that command doesn't exist, you get the error

> ```
> zsh: = not found
> ```

that you saw (and in fact, this same thing would happen even if you actually were using `/usr/bin/[`).

---

You *can* use `==` here if you really want. This works as you expected in zsh:

```
[ "a" "==" "a" ] && echo yes
```

because the quoting prevents `=word` expansion running. You could also disable the `equals` option with `setopt noequals`.

---

However, you'd be better off either:

- Using single [`=`, the POSIX-compatible equality test](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html); or
- Better still, **using the `[[` conditionals with `==`** in both [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_005b_005b) and [zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Conditional-Expressions.html#Conditional-Expressions). In general, `[[` is just better and safer all around, including avoiding this kind of issue (and others) by having special parsing rules inside.

Comment: What's the exact difference between `[` and `[[`? (Searching on Google for `[ vs [[` gives me results for `vs` only, LOL)

Comment: `[[` supports a wider range of tests in both cases, and has custom parsing rules that avoid the need for quoting variables, operators, and so on. If you're specifically using either Bash or zsh, use `[[`. If you're writing a portable script, write to the POSIX-compatible `[`/`test` command (which may or may not be a real command on your running system).

Comment: i'm doing this inside my `zshrc` for exporting `$TERM` when using `xfce4-terminal` (replacing `xterm` to `xterm-256color`)

Comment: Just use `[[` there and forget `[` exists.

Comment: you know... i disagree with your recommendation. `[[` is *differently* capable. try this with it: `for f in *; do [ -e "$f" ] && for a in f d h p S b c; do [ "-$a" "$f" ] && for p in r w x u g; do [ "-$p" "$f" ] || p=-; a=$a$p; done && break; done && printf "%s:\t%s\n" "$a" "$f"; done`.

Comment: @mikeserv: Oh, absolutely. If you're not trying to do something clever, you're much less likely to shoot yourself in the foot with `[[`, though. It's good advice to anyone who needs the advice, and anyone who doesn't need it knows why I'm wrong.

Comment: ^with that I completely agree. i dont much like the way `[[` refuses to be scripted - everything has to be explicit on its command-line. it's why i like `[` because it accepts arguments like most others. but, `[[` is a lot less to worry about if you like to do a lot of typing. though that thing isn't all that clever - it just loops over normal file attributes.

Comment: anyway.,, mine was your second upvote. agreement aside : its a good answer, and the information is useful, as usual.

Comment: Well, `=`/`==` is arguably one case where `[[` is not better than `[`, as `[[ a == b ]]` is _does "a" match the "b" pattern_ and not _is "a" equal to "b"_ as you'd expect. That means you need to write `[[ $a == "$b" ]]` for instance. At least, with the `[` command, if you know how command parsing works, you know you need to write it `[ "$a" = "$b" ]` to prevent the split+glob operator like in other commands. With that in mind and if you don't use -a or -o, `[` is safe in POSIX conformant implementations.

Comment: @mikeserv, I'd argue that your example of something `[` can do that `[[` can't is really a demonstration of how using `[` allows code and data to be mixed, whereas '[[' forces them to be kept distinctly. I *like* forcing `eval`-type uses to be explicit; places where they're not are potential homes for security bugs. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - well, i'd argue that's boring - but im a jerk. you're entitled to your opinion, but i think that loop above is a very good example of how `[` and `[[` are *differently* capable - regardless of your stylistic choices. and it think, i fact, that your argument supports that as well - your stylistic choices are more favorable to one than the other - and so they must differ in capability somewhat...

Answer (score 4):

`[` is a shell builtin command in bash and in zsh:

```bash
$ type [
[ is a shell builtin
```

From the [*Shell Builtin Commands* documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html):

> Builtin commands are **contained within the shell itself**. When the name of a builtin command is used as the first word of a simple command (see [Simple Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Simple-Commands.html#Simple-Commands)), the shell executes the command directly, without invoking another program. Builtin commands are necessary to implement functionality impossible or inconvenient to obtain with separate utilities.

The official documentation (`$ help test`) only allows to use `=`:

> STRING1 = STRING2
>
> True if the strings are equal.

So, the correct expression would be:

```bash
$ [ "a" = "a" ] && echo yes
yes
```

What happens is that bash is a bit less strict. Supporting the `==` operator with `[` [seems to be a bash extension](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) and it is no recommended to use it:

> string1 == string2
>
> string1 = string2
>
> True if the strings are equal. When used with the [[ command, this performs pattern matching as described above (see [Conditional Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#Conditional-Constructs)).
>
> **‘=’ should be used with the test command for POSIX conformance.**

If you want to use `==`, you should use the `[[` keyword:

```bash
$ [[ "a" == "a" ]] && echo yes
yes
```

Keep in mind that `[[` is less portable (is not POSIX). But both bash and zsh support it.

Answer (score 2):

And zsh, and bash give the same answer (`type` is builtin too for both shells):

```
$ type -a [
[ is a shell builtin
[ is /usr/bin/[
```

Answer (score 1):

In both shells, `bash` and `zsh`, the `[` utility is a shell builtin. This is the shells implementation of that tool, it is used in preference to the binary `/usr/bin/[`. The different results you encounter is caused by different implementations.

---

In `bash`, the `[` utility accepts `CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS` as the `[[` compound command. According to bashs man page both `=` and `==` are valid:

```
string1 == string2
string1 = string2
        True if the strings are equal.  = should be used with the test command for POSIX
        conformance.
```

---

In `zsh`, the `[` utility attempts to implement POSIX and its extensions where these are specified. In the [specification of the POSIX test utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) there is no `==` operator defined.