# /root/.bashrc:157: = not found

Tags: bash, ubuntu, shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh

```
#Get client IP base on current logged in user
if [ $USER == 'root' ]
then
    ip="$(last | awk 'NR==1 {print $3}')"
else
    ip="$(echo $SSH_CONNECTION | cut -d " " -f 1)"
fi
```

> /root/.bashrc:157: = not found

Line 157

[image]

---

## Note

***I appended this line `source ~/.bashrc` to my `.zshrc` to***

```
vi .zshrc
source ~/.bashrc  # import all my quick aliases and fns
```

Comment: Why are you parsing (or attempting to parse) the `.bashrc` if you're using `zsh`?

Comment: I am so sorry, I updated my post. The issue now on line 157. I showed what it is.

Comment: I am trying to load make my .bashrc file also compatible with .zshrc.

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code. That way, we can actually _copy_ the code to test it and we don't need to manually type it out.

Comment: Only mean to show line number as Proof. Code is there also.

Comment: BTW, that `ip="$(last | awk ...` line to get the IP does not give you the current user's IP address.   It gives you the IP (or hostname or tmux pid & window, or login day name, etc) of the last user to cause `wtmp` to be updated, which isn't necessarily the current user.  Try  `who -m --ips` (GNU who), but note that reliably getting the current login's IP is more complicated than it initially seems, and if you're doing it from a profile script like .zshrc or .bashrc, you have to handle non-network logins (e.g. console/xterm/serial login, tmux or screen window, etc), and non-login shells too.

Comment: `$SSH_CONNECTION` is fairly reliable if you only allow network logins via ssh.  Use that first, and only try `who -m --ips` or `last "$USER"` or even `tty` if it's empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `zsh`, [`=cmd`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#g_t_0060_003d_0027-expansion) is a filename expansion operator that expands to the path of the `cmd` command. `=cmd` is similar to `$commands[cmd]`.

So here, with `==` in one of the arguments of the `[` command, that expands it to the path of the `=` command. As there's no command called `=` in your `$PATH`, that causes an error.

Compare:

```
$ echo =ls
/bin/ls
$ echo =junk
zsh: junk not found
```

The equality operator in the `[` command is `=`. The `[` command only does tests, it doesn't do any assignments, so there's no need to differentiate between an assignment operator and an equality comparison operator like there is in some other languages (with `=` vs `==` like in C or `:=` vs `=` in some others, etc).

So it should just be:

```
[ "$USER" = root ]
```

Still the `[` of `zsh`, like that of `ksh` also supports `==` as an alternative to `=`, but unless you disable the `equals` option (like it is in `ksh` emulation), you'd need to quote at least the first `=` to avoid that `=cmd` operator:

```
[ "$USER" '==' root ]
```

Note that while `$USERNAME` is automatically set by `zsh`, `$USER` is not (though it is set as an environ variable by some things like `login`).

To test whether you have superuser privileges, it's more robust to check that your effective user id is 0, which can be done in `zsh` or `bash` with `[ "$EUID" -eq 0 ]` or `(( EUID == 0 ))`.

See also:

- [What's the difference between single and double equal signs (=) in shell comparisons?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/72039/22565)

Answer (score 3):

This line is not really syntactically correct (but `bash` handles it):

```
if [ $USER == 'root' ]
```

You should use `==` only with `[[`...`]]`, and `=` otherwise. I'd also recommend you double-quote `$USER` if you're staying with `[`...`]` syntax

```
if [[ "$USER" == 'root' ]]
```

or

```
if [ "$USER" = 'root' ]
```

Comment: Will try that. Thanks for your advise and correction.

Comment: Related: [Why does `==` behave differently inside `[ … ]` in zsh and bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/255483/170373), [“==” logical operator and zsh version 5.7.x](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/502061/170373)