# How to take positional arguments in a function in zsh?

Tags: zsh

I have a function defined as follows in my zshrc

```
function k8sapi() {
    PREFIX='https://STABLE_URL'
    if [ "$1" == "prod" ];
    then
        PREFIX='https://PROD_URL'
    fi

    echo "1 --> $1"
    echo "2 --> $2"
    curl -s "${PREFIX}/${2}"
}
```

When I run this:

```
$ k8sapi stable foo
k8sapi:2: = not found
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I look at arguments to a function in zsh?

These functions were copied over from my old laptop using bash shell, so I am trying to migrate them to zsh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your `if` condition. You should use just one `=` or you can also use `[[ condition ]]`.

```bash
 if [[ $1 == "prod" ]];
 then
    PREFIX='https://PROD_URL'
 fi
```

**Or:**

```bash
 if [ "$1" = "prod" ];
 then
    PREFIX='https://PROD_URL'
 fi
```

Comment: Thank you! Is that a ksh oddity? Why didnt it fail in bash?

Comment: @feroze In zsh, the  `=`  is an expansion. Try running `echo =mkdir`. 
This [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/255483/414186) explains why `zsh` fails to use `==`. (you can quoting `"=="` and it will work)